# having a condition to fragment adding

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, conditional-statements

for the last 4 hours ive been trying to understand how to do it.
to be clear, i need to add a fragment under a certain condition and for my purpose the condition can be either:
a. if the parent's id matches to what i seek.
b. if the fragment's id matches to what i seek.

i tried to put the condition inside the fragment itself:

```
public class BlockFrag extends Fragment{
SharedPreferences sp;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    sp =  getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myOptions", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int id = container.getId();//didn't work(i think the container is null for some reason
    switch (id)
    {
        default: return inflater.inflate(R.layout.nothing, container, false);

        case (R.id.redFrame): {
            if (sp.getBoolean("redBlock", true)) {
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.block_frag, container, false);
            }
        }
        case (R.id.greenFrame): {
            if (sp.getBoolean("greenBlock", true)) {
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.block_frag, container, false);

        }
```

i also tried to get the condition programatically but i cant understand how to prevent the fragment to automatically generate when i call the layout it's placed.

this is the layout it's placed for example

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/redFrame"
        android:layout_weight="0.33333">


        <fragment
            android:name="com.example.dor.myapplication.BlockFrag"
            android:id="@+id/blockRed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/block_frag"/>
```

this is the fragment's layout if it matters...

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="118dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/blockFrag"
    android:src="@drawable/block"
    android:layout_weight="0.33333"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

thank you for helping, any kind of way to do this will help me.

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing, couldn't you do the same thing by checking `Fragment#getId()`?  Use "blockGreen" for green frame and "blockRed" for red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leigh thank you for your answer but i don't know if you didn't understand my question or i didn't understand your answer...

anyway, i solved my problem through programatically adding the fragment in r=the onCreate of the activity and inserting the adding to an "if"

```
    BlockFrag rb = new BlockFrag();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();//declaring Fragment Manager
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();// declaring Fragment Transaction

    if(condition)
    {
        editor.putBoolean("redBlock", true);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.redFrame, rb);//adding the fragment
    }
```

needless to say i didn't declare the fragment in my activity layout and didn't perform any changes in the fragment class or fragment xml layout.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar earlier, I had to decide based on a value from `PickHeaderFragment` which `Fragment` to show inside my `root_frame_body`, here's how I achieved it:

My Parent or Host `Fragment`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/root_frame_header" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root_frame_body" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Inside my Host `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pick, container, false);
    headerFragment = PickHeaderFragment.newInstance("");
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_frame_header, headerFragment).commit();
}
```

My `PickHeaderFragment` has an `OnPickHeaderFragmentInteractionListener` Interface implemented which looks like this:

```
public interface OnPickHeaderFragmentInteractionListener {
    public void onFragmentInteraction(int res);
}
```

I ensure my Host `Fragment` will implement this interface by adding it during `onAttach` (inside `PickHeaderFragment`) like so:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        Fragment f = getParentFragment();
        mListener = (OnPickHeaderFragmentInteractionListener) getParentFragment();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}
```

Now, when the enter `Button` inside my `PickHeaderFragment` is clicked I call this event to let my Host `Fragment` know to change the `root_frame_body`:

Inside my Host `Fragment` I have:

```
@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(int res) {
    if (res == R.id.btnEnter) {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_frame_body, new PickByItemBodyFragment()).commit();;
    }
}
```

I am now able to change the layout (or which `Fragment` is displayed) in my Host `Fragment` after an event occurs inside a child `Fragment`.

**Note**: In my example I have nested `Fragments`, but you could just as easily have several `Fragments` within an `Activity`.

In summary I would recommend you follow a similar pattern of having a host `Activity` or `Fragment` and ensuring you have a `FrameLayout` added to your view to allow you to inflate whatever `Fragment` you need.

An added benefit to doing it this way is that you can segregate your code into separate `Fragments` also.