# Loading a fragment upon a specific condition

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, rewardedvideoad

I have an issue please help me out. I am building an android application and I have successfully integrated Rewarded video ads to it.

I want to show a fragment or auto redirect to a specific fragment when the below condition is met:

```
@Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
// I want to redirect the user to a particular fragment here. 
}
```

So Please help me out, if there is any other way to achieve this then please let me know.

Comment: So what is the issue ? Don't you aware of _FragmentTransaction_ with _FragmentManager_?

Comment: I am just starting out with android kindly help me.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-fragmentmanager-and-fragmenttransaction-example-replace-fragment-with-another-fragment-using-button-onclicklistener)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [having a condition to fragment adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079669/having-a-condition-to-fragment-adding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Fragment Manager and Fragment Transaction Manager for this.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_framelayout_id, new your_fragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Write below code inside your onRewarded :

```
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new FragmentA();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Here **fragment_container** is a FrameLayout defined inside your Activity on which you want to host your fragment.

I am mentioning a sample activity with a framelayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Below is a fragment Container" />
     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="match_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```